# Font transparency set to 255 in Codenameone GUI Builder bugs

Tags: codenameone

Setting the Font transparency to 255 makes the font fully transparent. I must set it to 254 to avoid this.

Comment: I have no idea what font transparency is? We have bg transparency and the gui builder also offers opacity as an option. Can you provide some screenshots, generated XML/Java Source and explanation on whether this happens within the GUI builder itself, generated code or elsewhere?